# Mail Merge Codes per Price Set Option (Name Badges)

Tags: price-sets

We would like to print name badges for our events using CiviCRM.

However, we use complex price sets, and we use "Codes" printed on our name badges for access to certain events.

Is there a way to use CiviCRM to merge price set options onto name tags?

We ended up using Excel and a lot of complicated formulas.

However, if every price set option could have a "Name Badge Code" field, and we could print those on the CiviCRM Name Badge, or even just export them in a price set report, that would substantially reduce our efforts.

Anyone ever face this issue?

Comment: We have a similar need and want to include on each badge the attendees role, membership level, and a short code for their fee level. We have been doing an Excel export and mail merge, which is not too bad for advance registrations, but unworkable for on-site registrations. We would also like to be able to include static text fields and concatenate fields such as city and state. I looked for the PHP pages for badge formatting and did not find which files would need to be modified-- has anyone had success with customizing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! You have posted this as an answer but it doesn't appear to answer the question.  You are more likely to get a response if you post a new question, with a reference to this question if relevant.

Comment: For onsite registrations, we had two laptops with name-badge printers and just hand typed their name/codes and printed it out on the spot.

Comment: I imagine some really nifty-cool extension could add a field to the price set field options for inserting a "name badge code" then it could be exported somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Custom Search: Price Set Export, then used Excel Formulas, and then a Microsoft Word Mail Merge. Ew!