# Possible to add extra field to event price set options?

Tags: price-sets

Has anyone thought about/had success with adding an additional text field to price set options? We are having to use excel to merge our price set labels into "codes" which we then use to make name badges. If we could just put the "code" on the price set option itself, it would make life much easier!

Comment: Here is a related discussion from the past; https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15762/mail-merge-codes-per-price-set-option-name-badges?rq=1